# Error in f(init, x[[i]]) : incompatible dimensions in R

Tags: r

I have an index (v2x_regime) that categorizes the regimes as democracy and autocracy. So it is a binary variable, 1 indicates democracy and 0 indicates autocracy. SuPDem variable is the level of support. I would like to see how autocracies and democracies' SuPDem values correlate. Does the support in autocracies correlate with the support in democracies? I want to see this.

My code gives is the following:

```
Reduce(cor, split(output1$SuPDem, output1$v2x_regime))
```

And it gives the error: Error in f(init, x[[i]]) : incompatible dimensions

How can solve the issue?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do here. `cor` takes two equal-lengthed vectors as arguments and returns a single value.  `split(output1$SuPDem, output1$v2x_regime)` will return a list of vectors. If the first vector in the list is a different length from the second vector, you will get this error. But even if all the vectors are the same length, the second iteration will fail, because the output of the first iteration will be a single value. `Reduce` will then try to run `cor` with the first argument being that single value, and the second being the second vector.

Comment: Could you perhaps explain what you are trying to achieve, so that we can give you some advice? My guess is that you haven't really understood what `Reduce` is supposed to do.

Comment: I edited my question. Now I think it is clearer. Thank you, Allan!

Comment: Perhaps you can try `z <- split(output1$SuPDem, output1$v2x_regime); cor(z[[1]], z[[2]])`

Comment: dimensions are incompatible still. Error in cor(z[[1]], z[[2]]) : incompatible dimensions :/

Comment: Then your vectors must be different lengths, so they are not in correspondence to one another. You can't measure correlation like that (you need to have two vectors of the same length, where the vectors are different variables measured in the same observation, like two vectors of height and weight, where each row of the two columns represents a single individual) . Perhaps try a `t.test`? `t.test(z[[1]], z[[2]])` to compare the supDem between the two regime types?

Comment: how z[[1]], z[[1]] represent SuPDem for autocracy and democracy. I could not understand that.

Comment: When you use split, you are creating a list of two vectors: the SuPDem values where regime is 1, and the supDem values where regime is 0. We are just storing this list with its two vectors to z.